# Can one pass an array of objects as an argument within the object window.dialogArguments?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, shared-objects, showmodaldialog

I am working on an AngularJS 1.x project with an ASP.NET Web API 2.2 backend. I would normally handle this in the normal Single-Page Application (SPA) fashion. However I have receive some strange requests to do... popup dialogs (remember... window.showModalDialog() ).

I have got most of this working, however I have run into something odd. When passing the shared object ('sharedObject' between popup dialog and Angular SPA) 'window.dialogArguments' back to the Angular front end, it tends to only love key/value pairs. It does not want an array of any sort.

I want to pass an array of file objects or a 'FileList' back to the AngularJS front end through 'windows.dialogArguments'. I want to do this from an input that follows:

```
    <input id="upldDcmnts" 
           name="upldDcmnts"
           type="file"
           multiple />
```

I have tried the following most straightforward approach:

```
    window.dialogArguments.UploadFiles = 
      document.getElementById( "UpldDcmnts" ).files;
```

... and appended them to the FormData object in an Angular controller as follows:

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append( "upload_files", sharedObject.UploadFiles );
```

This fails with the following error form the F12 Debugger for Internet Explorer (IE) 11:

```
    TypeError: Permission denied
```

If some one could, please explain how I can pass an array of file objects from the upload input to the angular front end through 'window.dialogArguments'.

The form setup appears to be correct. It has a 'name' attribute and...

```
 enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

NOTE: I understand this is unconventional, however the customer is a long time Windows user and won't have it any other way (please believe I have tried to talk them into another way and have become mean spirited in the process...). I understand a SPA modal can be used and looks prettier but it does not matter in this case.

Comment: Maybe you could workaround passing a json "string" and decoding (`json_decode($json, true)`) into array on the dialog box

Comment: That seemed obvious at first, but it appears the only thing useful is the file object.

Comment: I have narrowed the problem down to being able to add an array or list of objects to window.dialogArguments. If I could do this my problem would be solved.